# How to match nginx location block for non-whitespace character

Tags: nginx, regex, pcre

I'm trying to configure a workaround for google's [WontFix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30636) search behavior in nginx by having a simple subfolder for my searches.

So far this is what I have.

```
 location ~* ^/search/(.*\..*)$ {
    return 307 http://$1;
  }
 location ~* ^/search/(.*)$ {
    return 307 https://www.google.com/search?q=$1;
  }
```

However this matches spaces, how can I update the first location block to only match non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced `*` with `\S+` was all I needed. (found what I needed in [another exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181271/regex-to-match-a-single-character-that-is-anything-but-a-space))

```
 location ~* ^/search/(.\S+\..\S+)$ {
    return 307 http://$1;
  }
 location ~* ^/search/(.*)$ {
    return 307 https://www.google.com/search?q=$1;
  }
```

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer if you found it please. :)